# Why .net framework change causes mvc version conflict

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dll, frameworks, version

I have updated my .net framework from 4.5 to 4.6.But I am getting this error:

> Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 System.Web.Mvc.dll

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: You did not describe what  changes you have made or from which version to which version you have updated. Question should be more descriptive otherwise it becomes hard to guess why you actually facing the problem.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved.

Here I was referring the the dll version of System.Web.WebPages is Version=2.0.0.0 .which was wrong..

I have removed the current reference and added the new dll for System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0

Its solved.